# what does mAdvertiseFlags = -1 means in the Android BLE Application?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

While runnig a BLE android App I am getting mAdvertiseFlags = -1 in the adblog for  a given Mac ID of a wearbale_X , what does -1 means?Sometime mAdvertiseFlags  becomes 4.
For some  other wearbale_Y I get mAdvertiseFlags =6 continously .

Answer (score 0):

Advertising flags indicate the discoverable mode and capability of the device.

`-1` means that the `mAdvertisementFlags` was not yet. In other words, there are no advertisement flags.

Source: ScanRecord source code:

```
/**
 * Returns the advertising flags indicating the discoverable mode and capability of the device.
 * Returns -1 if the flag field is not set.
 */
public int getAdvertiseFlags() {
    return mAdvertiseFlags;
}
```

Comment: who sets it?The firmware in my wearable and not the Android?If it is -1 that means my wearable is not in discover-able mode or not advertising?

Comment: @Raulp seems so, yes. `mAdvertiseFlags` is set in `ScanRecord.parseFromBytes()`, while parsing a scanned advertisement

Comment: `-1` has no other meaning than "there were no special flags set". It is advertising, and it is discoverable, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: Yes true even if it is -1 it means it is advertising but I think not the intended data.I checked the logs with both mAdvertiseFlags = -1 and 4 and found that with mAdvertiseFlags = 4 it advertises values like : mServiceUuids,mServiceData which is null in case of mServiceData = -1.So it is aligned with the section you pasted that with -1 No device capability will be Known via its service Id or Service data(as it is null while in case = "4"it is not  and has a valid status good enough for finding the capability of the device).What are your comments?

Comment: Sorry, can't tell you more, the exact causes of flag values are not documented